# Why do the images keep on resizing as I scroll through my UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

All the images load fine and display with their width as the phone and their height as determined by the aspect ratio of the photo. Initally all of the photos except for the third one load in this manner, after scrolling out of view of the image and back the image resizes correctly but intially the image is just in scaleaspectFill with out the proper width and height.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorageUI

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
var images:[UIImage]! = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "rininger_2.jpg")]
var imageURLS:[String] = [String]()
var listener:ListenerRegistration?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    /////////
    listener = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener{
        querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            if (diff.type == .added) {
                print("New data: \(diff.document.data())")
            }
            if (diff.type == .modified) {
                print("Modified city: \(diff.document.data())")
            }
            if (diff.type == .removed) {
                print("Removed city: \(diff.document.data())")
            }
            // self.numberOfRows = snapshot.count
            // Parse each post


            //self.labels.append(newLabel)


            //Update TableView
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //This would reload everything creating a flash
                //self.tableView.reloadData()
                guard let newImageURL = diff.document.data()["imageDownloadURL"] as? String else{
                    print("Failed to get image download URL")
                    return
                }
                //let newLabel = Post(snapshot:diff.document)
                print("downloadURL: \(newImageURL)")
                self.imageURLS.insert(newImageURL, at: 0)
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)

            }
        }
    /////////
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return imageURLS.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Reuse", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    ///////////////////////
        let downloadURL = URL(string: imageURLS[indexPath.row])

            //cell.cellImageView.sd_setImage(with: downloadURL, completed:nil)
            //cell.cellImageView.image = self.images[indexPath.row]
    do{
        let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(string:(imageURLS[indexPath.row]))!)
        cell.cellImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
    catch{
        print("unable to load data: \(error)")
    }
            cell.cellImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let aspectRatio = Float((cell.cellImageView?.image?.size.width)!/(cell.cellImageView?.image?.size.height)!)
            tableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)/aspectRatio)

    ///////////////////////
    return cell
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the `clipsToBounds` property on `UIImageView` is set to `true`.

Comment: Thank you for your response unfortunately its not so simple, I have tried setting the constraints to be zeroed out for all bounds. I believe it is related to the Queue.